# Redis: when delete item exists in multiple list and set

Tags: c#, redis

I'm a newbie with redis.

Currently i'm using redis to stored posts

- urn:post:1
- urn:post:3
- urn:post:5
- ...

i stored posts that posted by user in list like this

- urn:user:1:posts => [1,3,4,5]
- urn:user:2:posts => [2,3,5,6,7,8,9]
- ...

i also stored list of latest posts in list

- urn:post:lastest => [9,8,7]

My question is if i remove one post, ex: del urn:post:1

How to remove that post's id in all list (or set) has it
Thank a lot

Comment: Your example makes no sense. How can posts 3 and 5 be associated to users 1 and 2 at the same time?

Comment: User 1 may created post with id = 1, and like post with id  =5.

Comment: So you need to separate them in two different structures. And use sets instead of lists to get O(1) behavior at insert and delete time.

Answer (score 0):

As you use NoSQL updating of "foreign keys" is up to you. I would use http://redis.io/commands/lrem

But note that you have to remove the data in correct order. I mean that it's necessary to remove those references where some of your queries can find reference to the content. It means that I would remove article id from posts and latest and than remove a post itself.

Comment: Thank for your fast answer but there is not "foreign keys" in this  scenario.

Comment: And what is post id (e.g. 1) mentioned in _urn:user:1:posts:_?